# Why is ; (semicolon) not showing an exception?

Tags: java

While I was working with the [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) IDE, I suddenly found that I had put double semicolons in a variable declaration.

Below is my statement

```
double defaultValue = 0.0;;
```

I am getting confused here. I expected the above statement to throw an exception, but I wrote the above statement and it ran without any error.

Why are double semicolons not showing an error?

Comment: If you prefer this to show an error, I'm sure plenty of static analysis tools would flag such code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an empty statement; that's all. It's perfectly legal, though usually useless. It's specified in [section 14.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6):

> An empty statement does nothing.
>
> *EmptyStatement:* 
>       ;
>
> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

Just about the only time I've ever *actually* seen it used was to give a loop an empty body, e.g.

```
while (somethingWithSideEffects())
    ;
```

Personally I'd prefer to use braces in that case (or change the code to not use side effects in that way), but that's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of exception would you have expected?

```
double defaultValue = 0.0;;
```

Is just the declaration of a `double` called `defaultValue` with value `0.0` followed by an *empty statement*.

You can put as many semicolons there as you want. They simply do nothing in this situation

```
double defaultValue = 0.0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

And just for terminology sake: There would be no *exception* - if anything there would be a compile warning or error. Syntax errors are nothing that occur at runtime and could throw errors, the compiler is there to catch those mistakes early.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any error, because it is an **empty statement** when you do `;`.

Your code is equivalent to

```
double defaultValue = 0.0; // Valid statement
;   // An empty statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Double semicolon isn't illegal.  It's just an empty code line.  No errors thrown.

You can even put them after a class declaration if you want to (from the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf)):

> Extra ";" tokens appearing at the level of type declarations in a compilation unit have no
> effect on the meaning of the compilation unit. Stray semicolons are permitted in the Java
> programming language solely as a concession to C++ programmers who are used to placing
> ";" after a class declaration. They should not be used in new Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler sees it as an empty statement.

`;` is supposed to be a delimiter to signify the end of a statement.

```
while(true);;;;;// Compiles and runs fine, but it will crash your PC
```

Comment: well, that will just crash your program.

Comment: @luk2302 it's just a example , try at your own peril :)

Comment: It will (probably) not crash the PC. It is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
double defaultValue = 0.0; // Correct statement
;   // Called as an empty
```

That’s why the compiler doesn’t give any error.